# I would like for the script to NOT run on every Thursday and the last Business day of the month

Tags: powershell, getdate

****Edit****

I am attempting to make a PowerShell script recognize what day of the week it is and decide whether to run. I have a script that performs the task; however, I need to be able to have it not perform the task on every Thursday and the last day of business for the current month. I was looking at the “get-date” command but was not able to get the correct parameters in place to stop the script form running under the previously listed conditions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.s. I did do a search SO and found serval commands that will identify the first day of the month and the last business day, but I was not able to get a possible answer for not running on a specific day of the week and the last business day of the month.

Comment: @mklement0 

thank you for pointing that out... The answer is Yes, I will need to observe all the United States Federal Holidays...

"Are you looking to let the script itself decide whether it should run, or are using a scheduler where the logic should reside? If so, which?"

I would like to have the script to be able to run independently. I was planning on only  use Task Scheduler to start the script. 

I hope that answers your question...

Comment: please REMOVE the code that has nothing to do with your Question. for instance, the `$Key` section is both undefined in your code AND has nothing to do with deciding when to run/not-run the rest of the script. actually, ALL of your posted code has undefined things in it ... and has nothing at all to do with your Question.

Comment: @JFlour - have you tried searching for >>> `determine last business day of month` <<< or >>> `find current day of week` <<< in the SO search box yet?